# Enviar datos serializados de un datatable a otro metodo

Tags: c#

Soy principiante desarrollando en C# .Net y necesito su apoyo para ser el siguiente insert. los datos de un DataGridView los almacene en un DataTable y lo serealice ,pero no se como enviarlo ese dato serializado a la clase que hace la inserción. espero su apoyo.

```
private void btnGrabar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvPais.Columns)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPais.Rows)
    {
        DataRow rows = dt.NewRow();
        for(int i =0;i < dgvPais.ColumnCount; i++)
             rows[i] = (row.Cells[i].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : 
               row.Cells[i].Value);

        dt.Rows.Add(rows);
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    StreamWriter streamWriter=new StreamWriter("xml.xml");
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, ds);
    enviarxml(streamWriter); ------------------------------------------------Error
}

private void enviarxml(StreamWriter xml)
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertXML",cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", xml);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!
 Podrias aclarar que error te da?

Comment: Necesitamos ver exactamente que error/excepción te lanza el código que nos muestras para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar el método **DataTable.WriteXml**

Aquí hay un ejemplo:

```
string result;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) 
{
    dataTable.WriteXml(sw);
    result = sw.ToString();
}
```

Si realmente no necesita una cadena sino XML de solo lectura procesable, es una mejor idea usar **MemoryStream** y **XPathDocument**:

```
XPathDocument result;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    dataTable.WriteXml(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    result = new XPathDocument(ms);
}
```

**SQL / C#**

```
SqlConnection sqlCon= new SqlConnection(CS);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (MyCol) values (@paramValue)", sqlCon);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paramValue", filteredXmlData));

sqlCon.Open();
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlCon.Close();
```